# Wrong url in paginate (kaminari) for search with %

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have paginate (kaminari) on search page, and if i search somthing with % like "50% discount" i get page `http://some.domain.com/50%25+discount` where paginate has wrong urls (without escaping %) like:
`http://some.domain.com/50%+discount?page=2`

Do i do somthing wrong? Or it's bug in gem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solutions is

`paginate @entities, :params => { :keyword => CGI.escape(@keyword) }`

in `route.rb` i have

`match "/:keyword" => "route#index", :keyword => /.*/`

Answer (score 0):

% is a special character in urls isn't it? Your going to need your search method to sanitize the query before it gets passed to the url.

I believe you can use the methods for the String class provided in the gem Stringex to sanitize the search term.

https://github.com/rsl/stringex

From there github page.

```
"10% off if you act now".to_url => "10-percent-off-if-you-act-now"
```

Edit:

You would need to have something like this (This isn't very clean but it gives you an idea)

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
     #Form in its view that goes to create via json
  end

  def create
     query = params[:query].to_url
     redirect_to "/search/#{query}"
  end

  def show
    #search paged on params[:query]
  end

end
```

routes

```
resources :searches, :only => [:new, :create, :show], :new => ""
get "/search" => "searches#new", :via => :get
```

You would be acting like your treating it like a normal object but your never actually saving it. You could even change the name of the :create method to parse if you want, but this way the built in rails helpers and logic will work.

Comment: Thank you for variant of solution. May be i will use it, if bug will not fix in few days.

Comment: try to search "10% off if you act now" in google, it normal escape this query

Comment: Its more meta code but yeah thats the whole point. And its not a bug of kaminari. % are not safe in urls. Thus passing one to the url will cause issues, so you got to make it safe some how, like above.