# ActiveAdmin pagination not working with Ruby 2.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, activeadmin, kaminari

This is the link generated by the pagination (i.e. page 2): http://localhost:5004/admin/end_customers?%23%3CProc%3A0x007fed48a49d80%40%2FUsers%2Fmartin%2F.rvm%2Fgems%2Fruby-2.3.1%2Fgems%2Ffacets-3.1.0%2Flib%2Fcore%2Ffacets%2Fsymbol%2Fcall.rb%3A24%3E=2&%23%3CProc%3A0x007fed494c6ba0%40%2FUsers%2Fmartin%2F.rvm%2Fgems%2Fruby-2.3.1%2Fgems%2Ffacets-3.1.0%2Flib%2Fcore%2Ffacets%2Fsymbol%2Fcall.rb%3A24%3E=2&order=id_desc

Decoded part of the URL ;) (for readability):

```
<Proc:0x007feb2adc4d90@/Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/facets-3.1.0/lib/core/facets/symbol/call.rb:24>=2&#<Proc:0x007feb35418638@/Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/facets-3.1.0/lib/core/facets/symbol/call.rb:24>=2&order=id_desc
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that I didn't clarify my issue enough. The problem is that one of the links generated by ActiveAdmin's pagination (Kaminari) is the one that I pasted here. For some reason it contains that estrange piece of code (or error) than then I decoded manually for readability.

It is happening with all my models, so I think it have to be related with ActiveAdmin or Kaminari.

Comment: This isnt a question

Comment: @thesecretmaster sorry, but I don't understand what is wrong with my question. I am having a problem with the ActiveAdmin gem, and posted the issue here to get some help.

Comment: But what is your specific issue?

Comment: Please share screen-shot instead of write localhost link,

Comment: @thesecretmaster Thanks for the help. I've just updated the issue with some clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @DineshSaini I don't know how a screenshot could help in this case, the layout is fine, it's just that the links of the pagination aren't working. (just updated the question with a more clarified brief). Thanks!

Comment: Can you see: please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994710/wrong-url-in-paginate-kaminari-for-search-with

Comment: @thesecretmaster Are you familiar with ActiveAdmin? It handles the entire layout, I don't have to put a single line of code regarding neither the table nor pagination. I just specified the model and its fields.

Comment: No, I'm not at all familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that facets gem is not fully compatible with the Kaminari or ActiveAdmin.

I fixed the issue by editing my boot.rb file where I required:

```
require 'facets'
```

Instead, now I only require a specific module:

```
require 'facets/time'
```

P.S. I got some help asking on ActiveAdmin's Github: [link](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4459)